# OSX KeyChain throws on trying to sign the data

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, keychain

I'm getting this weird error, which I can't find any additional information on, when my Objective-C code calls C++ library to sign the data with specified key:

```
Error Domain=Internal CSSM error Code=-2147416063 "Internal error #80010801 at __SignTransform_block_invoke.17 /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Security/Security-57740.31.2/OSX/libsecurity_transform/lib/SecSignVerifyTransform.c:279" UserInfo={NSDescription=Internal error #80010801 at __SignTransform_block_invoke.17 /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Security/Security-57740.31.2/OSX/libsecurity_transform/lib/SecSignVerifyTransform.c:279, Originating Transform=CoreFoundationObject}
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type ndn::SecurityException: Fail to sign data
```

The problem arises on second access to the private key. I.e. when I install certificate and run my application, it will prompt user with the "access" dialog which will ask user to explicitly allow access to the private key used during signing. After allowing, everything works as expected. However, on all consequent runs I'll experience the above exception. In order to proceed with testing I have to open KeyChain application and set "Allow all applications to access this item" explicitly in "Access Control" for this private key. Which is not a good practice. So far I couldn't find any explanation on why is this exception happening.

One thing I noticed though, is that this is happening for Cocoa implementation only - I mean, when I duplicated the Cocoa code in C++ test app, it doesn't crash.

The underlying library which performs signing uses [this](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cpp/blob/master/src/security/identity/osx-private-key-storage.cpp#L203) OSX signing function.

Comment: i met same problems a few years ego. if you delete your app from your phone or simulator, it will work perfectly. But you can met same problems in the future. You can use FDKeycahin https://github.com/reidmain/FDKeychain

Comment: @EmreGürses it's a desktop application.